# Java and MySql connection problem

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, connection

I am using Java+MySql. I am trying to add bulk data (around 40 million records). My application works fine for couple of hundred thousands records but after that it starts giving me following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2333)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2370)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2154)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor5.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at net.jboss.Database.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:48)
    at net.jboss.emp.idm.adta(mde.java:96)
    at net.jboss.emp.idm.main(mde.java:69)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
    ... 16 more
```

I googled this problem and tried almost every option (updating windows registry, changing my.cnf file, changing mysql global parameters etc.) but its not working.

Comment: please can u feel free to post ur jdbc drivers registered code here

Comment: Please show us your code. My guess is that you're opening the connection for every record, but forget to close it (you should only open it once and use a parameterized query afterwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems connection isn't being closed properly. I would recommend you to use c[onnection-pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool)

**Also See**

- [Connection pooling with MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/connection_pooling_with_connectorj.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am opening and closing connections properly. If this is the case then why does it work for first couple of hundred thousands records?

Comment: error message says `(maximum connections reached?)` probably after some transactions connection aren't being closed properly and so the result..

Comment: I double checked and didnt find any problem with total number of connections.

Answer (score 2):

I was hitting a similar problem a couple of hours ago. With the default settings, I could write some 15K records in a single transaction. Attempting to write any more than that gave me the exact same message ("No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect") .

I then broke down the transactions in chunks of 1000 records (my application requirements allowed for it) and I still received the message after the 15th iteration. My application was diligently creating a new EntityManager and closing it for each iteration.

The solution was to clear the cache for that particular type of entity in between iterations (you can also clear the cache by entity) .

EntityManagerFactory.getCache().evictAll or evict(...)

Answer (score 0):

this could be probably either lost connection with mysql or
your code could not be able to close existing connetction as u said it work for starting some records. so incresce max  connection with mysql or try to check with other program when u get this error message if mysql accept connection from other program.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and I fixed it by `connectionname.close();` statement after every time an executable statement is called.

Answer (score -1):

this can resolve your issue now :) 
[CommunicationsException](http://anuragpatil.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-failure-last-packet-sent-to-the-server-was-0-ms-ago/)

Comment: plz post the answer here rather than linking to your wordpress